# Physical location of Ethereum World State Trie

Tags: blockchain, ether, storage, database, leveldb

First of all, allow me to admit to a mistake I made on the other sites like this one, when I asked almost the same question. I feel it is ethical to explain this.

I mistakenly asked this question on stackoverflow and serverfault, but should have asked it here.

I was punished by being downvoted and reminded in a comment that I "should have not asked the question there".

All I ask that I be treated with some deference and politeness, and please don't downvote my question.

Those other sites I posted to said that this was a "general hardware" question rather than a programming question. I respectfully disagree with that.

The location of data storage directly affects the entire codebase and therefore many lines of actual code. I program in C++, nodejs, and python, and this question directly affects how I will write lines of code in these languages in enterprise applications and websites.

I would like to know PHYSICALLY and GEOGRAPHICALLY where the master "Ethereum World State Trie" is stored. Before taking on another contract, it is my ethical duty to be informed of this information.

I am a 3d-visual learner, and if I can see the hardware behind the software, it really helps me.

I understand how leveldb databases and tries work. The question is only where the master "Ethereum World State Trie" is stored physically and geographically.

One datacenter?
Multiple datacenters?
Multiple servers?
Mining computers?
Wallets?
Exchanges?
Every user's computer?

Is the master "Ethereum World State Trie" centralized or distributed?

Is there a specific data center or data centers that store the master "Ethereum World State Trie"?

Please note that I understand how the other components of Ethereum are stored.
I only need to know where, physically and geographically, the master "Ethereum World State Trie" is stored, regardless of whether it is at one datacenter or widely distributed.

Please give me a specific answer if possible.

Thank you so much for your time. You are all such wonderful, helpful people.
The world is a better place because of you, and you have driven so much of the
websites, applications, and internet technology for no money using your blood,
sweat and tears, metaphorically speaking. And for almost nothing in return.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Every full node in the Ethereum network holds a copy of the Ethereum state. So to answer your question literally, it's physically located in the storage (SSD or NVMe commonly) of any full node in the Ethereum network.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single "master Ethereum World State Trie", as said by KFitcher a copy is contained in every full node that participates in the Ethereum network.

The current "Ethereum World State Trie" can be constructed by executing all the transactions that were executed in the blockchain, so anyone with a copy of the blockchain could be able to reconstruct the complete trie.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ismael. Very informative and well written.